# Emberjs - Create 'Edit' action that edits a model without leaving '/models' url

Tags: url, ember.js, model, action, edit

I need help creating an 'edit' action that selects a specific model from a list of models, and in that table, edits the model. A quick-edit of sorts.

```
  <tbody>
    {{#each}}
      <tr class="people-list">
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
          <label class="category-text">{{#linkTo 'category' this}}{{Name}}{{/linkTo}}    </label>
          <img class="table-img" src="images/x.png">
          <img class="table-img" {{action 'edit'}} src="images/pencil-grey.png">
        </td>
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
```

By clicking {{action 'edit'}}, {{Name}} becomes and editable input. This is all done without  leaving the '/categories' url.

Thanks guys :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tbody>
    {{#each}}
      <tr class="people-list">
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
            {{#if isEdit}}
            {{input type="text" valueBinding="Name" name="Name"}}
            {{else}}
            <label class="category-text">{{#linkTo 'category' this}}{{Name}}{{/linkTo}}</label>
            {{/if}}
            <img class="table-img" src="images/x.png">
            <img class="table-img" {{action 'edit'}} src="images/pencil-grey.png">
            </td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

And then on the controller:

```
actions: {
    edit:function(){
        this.set('isEdit', true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I got the error 'GET http://localhost:3000/category/undefined 404 (Not Found) ' It still does not know what it is editing. Should I define isEdit = false?

Comment: That's a 404 error, which is entirely different.  Looks like you're working on a serialized route and your linkTo isn't set up correctly to match your map properties.

But this is a separate issue from the editing functionality.  You're getting that error from clicking the linkTo, not from clicking the edit.

Comment: Then this question is answered then! Thanks :) I've posted a follow-up question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21838322/emberjs-target-a-model-without-leaving-models-url

Comment: This is for a different question, but my {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="Name" name="Name"}} will not appear on the screen. Question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21884256/ember-js-view-not-displaying-ember-textfield-view-ember-textarea-valuebinding