# Emberjs, Target a model without leaving '/models' url

Tags: url, ember.js, model, action, edit

I have a table of models and I want to be able to click my `{{action 'edit'}}` in one of those model's  and ember will know which model # the `{{action 'edit'}}` is in.

Right now I am receiving this error: 'GET localhost:3000/category/undefined 404 (Not Found) '

Here is my code in the '/categories' route.

```
<tbody>
    {{#each}}
      <tr class="people-list">
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
            {{#if isEdit}}
            {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="Name" name="Name"}}
            {{else}}
            <label class="category-text">{{#linkTo 'category' this}}{{Name}}{{/linkTo}}</label>
            {{/if}}
            <img class="table-img" src="images/x.png">
            <img class="table-img" {{action 'edit'}} src="images/pencil-grey.png">
            </td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

And then on the controller:

```
actions: {
    edit:function(){
        this.set('isEdit', true);
    }
}
```

the 404 occurs when i click

```
<img class="table-img" {{action 'edit'}} src="images/pencil-grey.png">
```

and the model

```
VpcYeoman.Category = DS.Model.extend({
    RecordCategoryID:DS.attr('number'),
    Name: DS.attr('string'),
    ProjectName: DS.attr('string'),
    WorkDescription: DS.attr('string'),
    workflow: DS.belongsTo('category', {
        polymorphic: true
    }),
    classNameBindings: ['isAdministrator']
});

VpcYeoman.Calendar.FIXTURES = [

  {
    id: 0,
    RecordCategoryID: 0,
    Name: "Fire",
    ProjectName: "Electra"
  },

  {
    id: 1,
    RecordCategoryID: 1,
    Name: "Water",
    ProjectName: "Nike"
  }

];
```

and router.js

```
  this.resource('categories', { path: '/categories' });
  this.resource('category', { path: '/category/:category_id' },function() { 
    this.route('edit');
  });
```

I wasn't sure if i should have added anything about 'edit' to the router because i did not want the program to have to change URLs in order to focus onto a specific model.

Comment: Couple of additions that would be helpful:  1.  Your application map (the 404 and the 'undefined' in your url imply that this is a routing issue), 2. an example of your model structure, and 3.  What exactly you are clicking/doing to produce this error.

Comment: You need to use an itemcontroller in your each. Can you please create a JSFiddle to illustrate the problem?

Comment: I've updated the question. I can't set up JSFiddle for this type of question.

Comment: this.route('edit') should **not** be included.  You're handling the "edit" as an action, not a routing.  Try removing that line.

Answer (score 1):

There is a pretty simple solution, just send the model into the action.

```
<img class="table-img" {{action 'edit' this}} src="images/pencil-grey.png">

actions: {
  edit: function(model){
    model.set('isEdit', true);
  }
}
```

The undefined is coming from Ember trying to generate the url when you click the link-to.  It's taking the model then looking for `category_id` on the model to build the unique url.  Alas, you don't have that property on the model, so you need to fix up your route to tell Ember how to serialize your model.

```
App.CategoryRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  serialize: function(model){
    return {category_id: model.get('id')};
  }
});
```

Comment: Once i removed the 'undefined' error, I saw that both {{action 'edit' this}} and {{action 'edit}} were completely ignored by the program. No error or anything. Now if I used a different action like 'save', i would receive the error 'Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'save' '

Comment: You have an edit action, if you add a console.log, is it hitting it?

Comment: yes console.log('Testing console'); produces 'Testing console' in the console.