# Ember.js View not displaying Ember.TextField {{view Ember.TextArea valueBinding="Name" name="Name"}}

Tags: html, input, view, ember.js, each

I want to show this input so I may edit a category's 'Name', but the view is not displaying.

The result is only the Names for each Category appearing on the list. Each category should have it's own input with a value set to the 'Name' for that Category.

I am not receiving any errors, so what am I doing incorrectly?

```
  {{#each}}
   <tr>
     <td>
      {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="Name" name="Name"}}
      <label class="category-text">
        {{#linkTo 'category' this}}
          {{Name}}
        {{/linkTo}}
      </label>
     </td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

EDIT:

I've been playing around with implementing different input methods and none of them are showing up on the list of Categories! Waaah?

Here's what I tried:

```
<input type="text" Value="Name">
```

,

```
{{input type="text" valueBinding="Name" name="Name"}}
```

EDIT2:

```
VpcYeoman.CategoriesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        VpcYeoman.Category.FIXTURES=[];
        $.ajax({
            url: '/categories',
            dataType: 'json',
            type:"get",      
            async: false,
            success : function(data) {      
                VpcYeoman.Category.FIXTURES=data;
            }
        });
        return this.store.find('category');
    }
});
```

and

```
model: function() {
  return this.store.find('category');
},
```

Comment: Your `{{/each}}` should be moved one line lower so that it encompasses the `</tr>`.  I'm not sure if this is the cause of your problems or not, but it certainly won't help.

Comment: Good catch. I had that correct in my code but I miscopied it. I made your update in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think using `Ember.TextField` directly is recommended anymore, you should use `{{input value=name}}` instead. [More documentation on the input helper here.](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/input-helpers/)

Comment: {{input}} worked for me, but it has no value still. Now I am trying to assign it's value to the current 'category' it is in in between {{#each}}{{/each}}

Comment: If name is a regular property on a Ember model then it shouldn't be capitalised. Does it work if you use `name` instead of `Name`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [working JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yukejeju/4/edit?html,js,output) for what you're trying to do.  I'm not sure at which point you're having trouble, but you should try to match your system to be something like this.

Comment: Maybe it is something wrong with my model: defined in routes. I've updated my question.

Comment: Yup, it was a capitalization error with the name of the attr. Thank you.